# Interpreting AIC relative likelihoods ( qpcR::akaike.weights() )

Tags: r, model-selection, likelihood, aic

I want to ensure that I am correctly interpreting AIC relative likelihood (RL) scores, specifically those returned by `qpcR::akaike.weights$rel.LL`. For example, I compare two models, and get:

```
$rel.LL
[1] 0.0442598 1.0000000
```

Summing to 1.044. However, if I feed `qpcR::akaike.weights()` the same AIC twice, I get:

```
$rel.LL
[1] 1 1
```

Which sums to 2. I note that AIC weights always sum to 1, but RLs do not. Is the RL for the most plausible (lowest AIC) model always "1", with the other likelihood scores given in relation to the most plausible model? i.e., could one infer in the first example that the second model in the list is 22.59x more likely to be the "best" model than the inferior model (with a RL of 0.0442598), calculated as 1/0.0442598 = 22.59? The documentation for `qpcR::akaike.weights()` gives the formula, but I am not mathematically astute enough to infer exactly what I am looking at from the formulas. If I am unsure, perhaps others are too. Any advise would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Generally:

Relative likelihoods are *relative*. There is no reason that I can see for them to add to anything and setting one of them to 1 is arbitrary, but useful, as it lets us get a sense of the size of the other one in our heads and with no division.  Personally, I would make the *smaller* one equal to 1, but that's just me.

For your question, yes, this would mean that the second model is 22.59 times more likely. See [documentation for akaike.weights](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/qpcR/html/akaike.weights.html) in particular:

> relative likelihoods that demonstrate the probability of one model
> being in favor over the other.

Also, in the middle formula on that page, note that L is proportional to the right hand side of the equation, not equal to it. This confirms my thought from above.